# Split single line if statement into multiline if statements

Tags: java

I am trying to split single line if statement into multiline if statement with the same meaning. I have:

```
 if(a || (b && c))
 {
    /* do smt */
 }
```

but would like to change it to something like if I would have

```
if(a && b && c)
{
  /*do smt*/
}
```

with the same meaning of

```
if(a)
{
  if(b)
  {
     if(c)
     {
         /* do smt */
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the conditions `a`, `b` and `c` are too long, consider writing methods with short but descriptive names for those, e.g. `if (isLoggedIn(user) || (isGuest(user) && guestCanEdit(topic)))`

Comment: Whats your question? I didnt understand.

Comment: I will write an extended version of the question to be more clear. So the if statement is
`if(list.isEmpty() || (!list.isEmpty() && list.getLast().compareTo(heap.peek().value) <= 0))`

and it runs inside while loop. What am I trying to do here is to count how may times `compareTo()` method was called and I think I should split the if statement to count it more accurately.

Comment: Don't think in what you can do, think in context. The trice-fold ifs are quite ugly and make your code less readable. The code should read as much like a spoken sentence as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean algebra can turn this condiiton

**a || (b && c)** into

**(a || b) && (a || c)**

so you can do somthing like:

```
if(a || b)
 {
    if(a || c){
    /* do smt */
 } 
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @henrich Note that now your first condition is `if (list.isEmpty() || ! list.isEmpty())`. For your particular case, you do not need the outer `if` at all.

Comment: Handles the evaluation of a twice, not very effective if a requires a complex computation. Also wrong if a should happen to have side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this without repeating the body of the `if` block. You can transform `a || b` to `!(!a && !b)`, but while this uses an `&&`, you can't split this up into nested `if` statements due to the surrounding `!(...)`.

Why do you want to do this in the first place? My assumption would be that the three conditions `a`, `b` and `c` are very long and/or complex. If this is the case, I'd suggest one of the following:

- declare three boolean variables with descriptive names and use those in the condition

  ```
  boolean isLoggedIn = // some really long data base lookup
  boolean isGuest = // more data base stuff
  boolean guestCanEdit = // a complex boolean expression
  if (isLoggedIn || (isGuest && guestCanEdit)) { ...
  ```
- define three methods performing the above checks and use those in the `if`

  ```
  if (isLoggedIn(user) || (isGuest(user) && guestCanEdit(topic))) { ...
  ```

Note, however, that the first version does not use short-circuiting, i.e. all the conditions will be evaluated, even if the first is already true or the second is false. This should be avoided if any of the conditions in computationally expensive or e.g. if the third check is only possible if the second succeeds (e.g. after a `null` check).

---

Concerning your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955131/split-single-line-if-statement-into-multiline-if-statements/41955494#comment71089530_41955131): The condition

```
if (list.isEmpty() || 
        (!list.isEmpty() && list.getLast().compareTo(heap.peek().value) <= 0))
```

is not really *that* long, and I would not suggest any of the above methods for this, as it will not get much shorter that way. But you *can* shorten it, because the `b` part is redundant. Due to the short-circuiting of `||`, `(b && c)` are only evaluated if `!a`, and since your `b` *is* `!a`, you can shorten it to just `a || c`

```
if (list.isEmpty() || list.getLast().compareTo(heap.peek().value) <= 0)
```

---

If your goal is to count how many times `compareTo` is called, you can use this:

```
if (! list.isEmpty() && list.getLast().compareTo(heap.peek().value) <= 0)
```

Now this is just `b && c`, with the `a` part entirely missing. Note that this is *not* equivalent to `a || (b && c)` anymore, but in this case that's a good thing, because due again to the short-circuiting, `compareTo` would actually *not* be called in `a || c` if `a` already evaluated to `true`.

Comment: That is true @tobias_k  `if (list.isEmpty() || list.getLast().compareTo(heap.peek().value) <= 0)` is a better solution and thanks for that, but I am again not sure how to count how many times `compareTo()` was called (inside the loop) since there is `||` condition :/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, but perhaps you shouldn't.

---

`if (a && b) statement;`

is exactly equivalent to

```
if (a){
    if (b){
        statement;    
    }
}
```

But the same can't be said for `if (a || b)`: you'd need to write `statement;` in more than one place:

```
if (a){
    statement;
} else if (b){
    statement;
}
```

That said, `||` does *distribute* across `&&`, even with the short-circuiting property:

So

```
if (a || b && c/*redundant parentheses removed*/){
    statement;
}
```

can be written as

```
if ((a || b) && (a || c)){
    statement;
}
```

which, from above, is

```
if (a || b){
    if (a || c){
        statement;
    }
}
```

which, although unnecessarily obfuscated, is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The need for this is not very clear, but you could do this: Make it in a function:

```
function codeToDo() {
  // your code to execute on condition
}

if (a) {
  codeToDo();
else if (b) {
  if (c) {
    codeToDo();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a || b)
 {
     if(a || c){
    /* do smt */
     }
 }
```

To further handle `if(a||b)` part, apply:

```
if(a){
   /*do task1*/
}else if(b){
   /*do task1*/
}
```

Note that in the `if(a)` as well as `else if(b)`, you are running same code;i.e. task1.

Comment: Handles the evaluation of a twice, not very effective if a requires a complex computation. Also wrong if a should happen to have side effects.